# How to delegate a client connection from a server to another client

Tags: sockets, lua, network-programming, coronasdk, multiplayer

I'm building a lean game server using Lua. The server itself only provides game lobby features. It accepts client connections, allows players to join rooms (or games) and then delegate the clients information to the group and one of the client serves also as the game manager for the duration of the game with direct, peer to peer connections with the rest of the clients.

All clients successfully connect to the lobby server and the server send back their IP info so they can attempt to connect to each other. The problem I'm facing is that the clients fail to connect to game manager which is on one of the clients. It seems as if the IP is incorrect or incoming connections are blocked although the outgoing connection to the lobby works.

I'm new to multi-player programming so I might be missing something trivial but I couldn't find any helpful post about it.

Here are code snippets from the project:
The game manager on the selected client attempts to listen to incoming clients

```
function Server:connect()

    local tcp, err = socketlib.bind( '*', self.port )  
    if err then
        print("Game Instance Sever Error: ".. err)
    else
        tcp:settimeout( 0 )
        self.socket = tcp
    end

    local function pulse()
        repeat
            local client = tcp:accept()  
            if client then
                self:handleClient(client)
            end
        until not client
    end

    --== Start listening
    if self.socket then
        self.serverPulse = timer.performWithDelay( 100, pulse, 0 )
    end
    return self.host
end
```

And the client connect method to the game manager. It accepts the connection info from the remote server:

```
function GameClient:connect( connection_table )
    self.host = connection_table.host 
    self.port = connection_table.port 

    self.player_handle = connection_table.handle or nil

    --== Init socket
    self.socket = socketlib.tcp()

    --== Connect to server
    local success, msg = self.socket:connect( self.host, self.port )
    if success then
       --Do Something 
    else
       --Error
    end
end
```

Note that if I send on a local network (LAN) the internal client IP than the process succeeds and the rest of the clients can join the game. However, using the public IP of the client is not working. 
Also all clients are using dynamic IPs so we cannot build a predefined IP pool.

Comment: which libraries are you using?

Comment: Be aware that if the game manager is behind a NAT that you will need a hole punched through for it, either manually or via UPnP/PMP/etc.

Comment: I'm using Corona SDK socket library which is based on LuaSocket http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/

Comment: Joel C, That might be one of the issues. Thanks for the tip. I'll look it up to see how this may affect and how to circumvent it.